# TCPDF - images are not showing up

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm trying to save a pdf with some data from database and some images. I can save normally but images are not showing up. $ft1, $ft2 and $ft3 are database variables with image's names.

Here is my test code:

```
    require_once('../tcpdf/config/lang/bra.php');
    require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    //set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    //set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    //set some language-dependent strings
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $html.= "<div><img src='../uploads/".$ft1."' width='200' height='400' /><br><br><img src='../uploads/".$ft2."' /><br><br><img src='../../uploads/".$ft3."' /></div>";

    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

    $pdf->lastPage();

    ob_clean();

    $pdf->Output('../uploads/'.$norepeat.'_relatorio_'.$idcontrato.'_'.formatDataJustNumbers($_POST['datarelatorio']).'.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Relative paths?  Try with absolute and see if it works.

Comment: Other things to look at, read access to the images from the script, GD or IMagick installed, images a supported type, etc.  Usually people use double quotes on attributes in HTML.

Comment: **$html.= "<div><img src='../uploads/".$ft1."' width='200' height='400' /><br><br><img src='../uploads/".$ft2."' /><br><br><img src='../../uploads/".$ft3."' /></div>";** Should be: **$html .= '<div><img src="../uploads/'. $ft1 .'" width="200" height="400" /><br /><br /><img src="../uploads/'. $ft2 .'" /><br /><br /><img src="../../uploads/'. $ft3 .'" /></div>';** as Orbling said.

Comment: Thanks Orbling and Benny Hill, double quotes solved the problem. I'm also chmod to 777 my cache folder inside tcpdf folder.

Comment: 775 is what max you should assign..not 777..

Answer (score 4):

Old post, but I came here looking for help:

Official documentation states that all HTML attributes must be enclosed with double quotes.

```
width='200' height='400'
```

Needs to be:

```
width="200" height="400"
```

in order for the images to show. That fixed it for me.

REFERENCE:
https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_writeHTML

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 problems;

1. you need to use absolute path,
2. please change this line;

   $html.= "
   ";

in to this;

```
$html.= "<div><img src='../uploads/$ft1' width='200' height='400' /><br><br><img src='../uploads/$ft2' /><br><br><img src='../../uploads/$ft3' /></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check the bar before your absolut path**

For me the way to fix the image not displaying in the PDF was to remove the bar from the begining of he absolut path.

Example

Wrong for me:

```
 $image_file = '/assets/img/setor9.png';
 $this->Image($image_file, 165, 20, 25, '', 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Right:

```
 $image_file = 'assets/img/setor9.png';
 $this->Image($image_file, 165, 20, 25, '', 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running jobs to generate pdfs from HTML templates using tcpdf with a php-fpm docker image. I discovered that tcpdf appends $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for image src values that start with '/'. This resulted in no images showing in the pdf.

The work around was to set $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to an empty string.

```php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "";
```